# Error with assigning row names from existing dataframe column

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I have physical measurements that I have put into a csv, then imported into R for calcs. I found the mean and std of these measurements and assigned std with value NaN to zero.

The first column contains the (unique) names of different materials, and I'm trying to assign this column as the row names. This comes up with an error of: invalid 'row.names' length, despite the fact I'm using the first column from the dataframe.

```
data <- read.csv("my.csv", header = TRUE, fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM")
data <- data.frame(data)  %>% select_if(~sum(!is.na(.)) > 0) 
data_ave <- data %>% group_by(material) %>% summarise(mean_width = mean(width_cm), std_width = sd(width_cm))
data_ave$std[is.nan(data_ave$std_width)] <- 0
rownames(data_ave) <- data_ave[,1]

Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : invalid 'row.names' length
```

Also:

```
nrow(data_ave[,1])==nrow(data_ave)

TRUE
```

I've used a similar method successfully for another dataframe, then simply removed the first column. How can they have the same number of rows, and for the length of row.names to be the problem here?

Cheers for the help

Comment: Is `length(unique(data_ave[,1])) == nrow(data_ave)` `TRUE`?

Comment: Yes, all the row names are unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably that is because `data_ave` is a tibble. You cannot set rownames on tibble also `data_ave[, 1]` would return a tibble back unlike dataframes which will return a vector.

This can be demonstrated with this example.

```
library(dplyr)

data_ave <- mtcars %>%
                group_by(cyl) %>%
                summarise(mpg = mean(mpg))
rownames(data_ave) <- data_ave[, 1]
```

> Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : invalid 'row.names' length
> In addition: Warning message:
> Setting row names on a tibble is deprecated.

Solution is to change `data_ave` to dataframe.

```
data_ave <- data.frame(data_ave)
rownames(data_ave) <- data_ave[, 1]
data_ave

#  cyl      mpg
#4   4 26.66364
#6   6 19.74286
#8   8 15.10000
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, cheers, that worked brilliantly! After importing the csv and converting it to a dataframe, at which point did it convert to a tibble?

Comment: When you are using `data %>% group_by(material) %>% summarise....` that converts it into tibble. BTW there is `column_to_rownames` function which will turn column to rowname and delete the column for you automatically.

Comment: Thank you also for that tip! This is my first time asking a question here, thank you for making it a great experience